# Irrationality of a number represented by an infinite product, whose partial products are irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, products

It is known that infinite sequences of irrational numbers can converge to rational numbers. For instance, the sequence:
$$
\{x_n=\sqrt[n]{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty
$$
equals $1$ when $n\to\infty$, however it is irrational for all $n>1$.

But what about infinite products? For instance, let the function:
$$
f=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[b]{a},
$$

for $b\in\mathbb{N}$, $b>1$ and $a$ irrational such that $f$ converges to the real number $k$. We immediately see that all partial products are irrational. Can we then also say that $k$ is irrational? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{2}$ for all $n$ and $b_n =2$ for $n =1,2,3$ and $b_n=2^{n-2}$ for $n \ge 3$

Then you have $b_n$ as the sequence $2,2,2,4,8,16,\ldots$ and $\sum \frac{1}{b_n}=2$

So $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[b_n^{\,}]{a} = a^{\sum \frac{1}{b_n^{\,}}}=\sqrt{2}^2=2$$

which is an integer limit despite all the $\sqrt[b_n^{\,}]{a}$ being irrational

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. You are in fact letting $a=2$ here, not $\sqrt{2}$. I must have $a$ irrational, without the square root.

Comment: @Pickle.   I am saying $a=\sqrt{2}$ and the product is $\sqrt[2]{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[2]{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[2]{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[4]{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[8]{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[16]{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[32]{\sqrt{2}}\cdots$. The product of those visible terms is about $1.978$ and the limit is $2$

Comment: I could do something similar with any rational target and any irrational $a$ both greater than $1$: for example $\sqrt[2]{\pi}\,\sqrt[2]{\pi}\,\sqrt[11]{\pi}\,\sqrt[289]{\pi}\,\cdots$ fast approaches $\frac{7}{2}$ and I just choose the next term to get substantially closer to the target without reaching it

Comment: That's perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n \in \Bbb N$. Clearly, $p^{1/n}$ is irrational.

Now, consider a sequence $(n_i)_{i \in \Bbb N}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n_i}=1$.

Observe that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty p^{1/n_i} =p$.

Comment: @Peter: except $a$ is supposed to be irrational

Comment: @Henry Would it work with $a=\sqrt{2}$ and the sequence $1,1/2,1/4,1/8,\cdots$ giving $(\sqrt{2})^2=2$ ?

Comment: @Peter: Yes - that was my earlier comment on your earlier comment.  Though strictly the original question says you cannot have $1$ in the sequence; instead replace it with two $\frac12$s as in my answer